# Is the subset open/closed, bounded, compacted?

Tags: real-analysis

For a non zero vector $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $$U={x\in \mathbb{R}^2:⟨x,u⟩<1}$$

Is the subset open/closed, bounded, compacted?

I think it's open because 1 is not included in the set, bounded because it is a circle, and not compact because the set is not closed. Am I on the right track?

I am very new to real analysis, please let me know if there's any easier way to deal with these questions.

Comment: You’re on the right track but incorrect because the set of $v$ such that $\langle v,u \rangle=0$ is not bounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is open because it is the inverse image of $(-\infty ,1)$ under a continuous map.

It is not closed because it contains $(1-\frac 1 n) \frac u {\|u\|^{2}}$ for each $n$ and the limit $\frac u {\|u\|^{2}}$ of this sequence does not belong to the set.

It is not compact because it is not closed.

It is not bounded because is contains $- n \frac u {\|u\|^{2}}$ for each $n$.

Comment: Hi, how did you get $(-\infty , 1)$ as the inverse image?